# tomcat cannot reload context because of a background thread

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, background-process

I have a JSF2 project with Spring. It is developed on eclipse with tomcat attached to it. It is pretty straight forward and mostly with default settings.

But, we have a few background threads that look like this:

```
public class CrawlingServiceImpl implements CrawlingService, InitializingBean{
    private final Runnable crawlingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //...
        }
    };

    public void startCrawling() {
        crawlingThread = new Thread(crawlingRunnable);
        crawlingThread.start();
    }

    public void stopCrawling(){
        if ( crawlingThread!=null )
            crawlingThread.interrupt();
        crawlingThread = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        startCrawling();
    }

    public void destroy(){
        stopCrawling();
    }
}
```

Here's who's calling the `destroy()` method:

```
<bean
    id="crawlingService"
    class="com.berggi.myjane.service.CrawlingServiceImpl"
    autowire="byName"
    scope="singleton"
    destroy-method="destroy"/>
```

I know that there is a better way all this to be done. But this is not my code and I don't want to rewrite it.

My problem is the following:
When I change a class (every single time) or when I change an xhtml file (very rarely) the server attempts to reload it, but it fails with the following errors:

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.xml.dtm.ObjectFactory.findProviderClass(ObjectFactory.java:508)
    ...
    at package.CrawlingServiceImpl.crawl(CrawlingServiceImpl.java:92)
    at package.CrawlingServiceImpl$1.run(CrawlingServiceImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

**Note**: Check the stacktrace. There are a lot of these exceptions.

Then there are more exceptions for a missing jdbc driver which is absolutely fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd bite the bullet and rewrite it. This is really a bad way of running background processes in a Java EE web application.

Comment: I have to discuss it with my colleagues. BTW, what is a better way to implement background jobs with JSF and Spring?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure crawlingThread.interrupt(); is killing the running of the Thread.

Without seeing the code of run().  it looks like it probably has a method called crawl and it does 1 of 2 things

1) a loop which expects a boolean variable to stop it running, and some possible sleeps/waits.  I see an interupt, but no boolean being set to terminate the threads loop.

2) it runs once (no loop) and when finished dies - however, I don't see how the interupt will help here.

Assigning the Thread variable to null will not help to kill the thread.

if you want a quick fix, you could try set the thread to a daemon thread to allow it to be terminated.

```
private final Runnable crawlingRunnable = new Runnable() {
    {
        setDaemon(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //...
    }
};
        //...
}
```

But without the code, I'd guess the thread is refusing to die properly due to either issue 1 or 2.